# SSRS time of datetime parameter is not refreshing when Report autofresresh runs (every 30 seconds)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sqlreportingservice

I have two parameters in my report (SSRS).
First parameter: Yesterday date+time
Second parameter: Now date+time
I use the follow "expressions" commands to get those parameters when I run my report.
To get yesterday date+time:

```
=DateAdd("d",-1,Now())
```

and to get now date+time:

```
=Now()
```

I have set Autorefresh property to 30 seconds.
and when I run the report loads fine and after 30 seconds I see it to do something like refreshing but the datetime parameters on the top of the page keeps freezed so the values in my report are not changing.
How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not directly embedding then in you query SQL clause, eg WHERE mydate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()

Comment: Thank  you. Thats what i did. I put the clauses directly in the querys. I had to modify all my Datasets, but well, it worked. I added WHERE ([CaptureDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())